# Create a contract externally

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

As far as I know, creating a contract inside a contract using the `new` operator appends the bytecode of the new created contract to the creating contract, which effectively extends the original contract. As a result, contract size can exceed the 24KB limit in deployment.

I am wondering if there is a contract creation pattern that the new contract is separated from the original contract and can still be accessed in the existing fashion. Thanks.

Below is an example of initiating a new contract in a contract. Check out the bytecode for what I meant.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.4;

import "./1_Storage.sol";

contract Test {
    
    Storage stg;
    constructor() {
        stg = new Storage();
    }
    
    function getter() public view returns(uint256) {
        return stg.retrieve();
    }
    
    function setter(uint256 val) public {
        stg.store(val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once deployed, the bytecode is immutable (except for the combination of `selfdestruct` and `create2` opcodes which allow destroying and redeploying new bytecode on the same address).

The `stg = new Storage();` deploys an instance of `Storage` to a new address and returns the instance in `stg`. **It does not extend the already deployed bytecode.**

```
event LogAddress(address _address);
    
Storage stg;
constructor() {
    stg = new Storage();
    emit LogAddress(address(stg));
}
```

This returns different values for `from` (the emitting `Test` contract) and `_address` (the deployed `Storage` contract)

```
[{
    "from": "0x7EF2e0048f5bAeDe046f6BF797943daF4ED8CB47",
    "topic": "0xb123f68b8ba02b447d91a6629e121111b7dd6061ff418a60139c8bf00522a284",
    "event": "LogAddress",
    "args": {
        "0": "0xD9eC9E840Bb5Df076DBbb488d01485058f421e58",
        "_address": "0xD9eC9E840Bb5Df076DBbb488d01485058f421e58"
    }
}]
```

---

The bytecode of the `Test` contract address contains the `Storage` contract definition as well because of the `import "./1_Storage.sol";` statement. But if you ran `stg = new Storage();` 10 times, the original bytecode would not change - it would just deploy `Storage` to 10 different addresses.

You can test it by moving the `stg = new Storage();` outside of constructor to a separate function. You'll see that after executing the separate function, bytecode on the `Test` address will not change.

---

Edit: If you want to lower the size of the "base" factory contract, you can deploy just proxies to your implementation. The implementation needs to be still deployed somewhere, but it can be outside of your contract.

Implementation on address `0x123`

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Storage
    bool initialized;
    uint256 value;

    constructor() {
        initialized = true;
    }

    function init() external {
        require (!initialized, 'Already initialized');
        initialized = true;
    }

    function retrieve() external returns (uint256) {
        return value;
    }

    function setter(uint256 val) external {
        value = val;
    }
}
```

Factory on address `0x456`

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface Storage {
    // only need the `init()` definition, other functions are not used here
    function init() external;

    // mind that this is just an interface, the implementation is on address 0x123
}

contract Factory {
    function createStorage() external returns (address target) {
        // 0x123 is the implementation address
        address target = createMinimalProxy(address(0x123));
        // init function instead of constructor (because the contract has already been deployed), you can pass arguments if you need
        Storage(target).init();
    }

    function createMinimalProxy(address _implementation) internal returns (address result) {
        bytes20 implementationBytes = bytes20(_implementation);
        assembly {
            let clone := mload(0x40)
            mstore(clone, 0x3d602d80600a3d3981f3363d3d373d3d3d363d73000000000000000000000000)
            mstore(add(clone, 0x14), implementationBytes)
            mstore(add(clone, 0x28), 0x5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf30000000000000000000000000000000000)
            result := create(0, clone, 0x37)
        }
    }
}
```

This example uses the [EIP-1667 minimal proxy](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1167) (it's literally 45 bytes built in the `createMinimalProxy()` function).

Each time `createMinimalProxy()` is executed, it deploys the minimal proxy (the 45 bytes) to a new address and returns the new address.

Because of the `delegatecall` instruction (within the proxy contract), when a user calls (or executes a function on) the proxy, **the call uses bytecode of the implementation - but storage of the proxy.** So multiple proxies can point to the same implementation and they all use separate storage.

You can find another code snippet in [this article](https://soliditydeveloper.com/clonefactory) for example.

Comment: This is helpful and clear. The reason I'm asking this question is I have a factory contract that is generating new instances of a contract which generates a new contract itself. As you said, importing the definitions of this contract extends the size of this contract. I am just wondering how a new contract in a contract can be generated externally without first importing it, hence reducing the size of a contract significantly. I'm tyring a clone method, but it still first requires importing the template contract.

Comment: @Maxareo You can deploy proxies (instead of the actual implementation) in your factory. I edited my answer with an example of a "minimal proxy factory".

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Another quick question is: does clone also clone the values in a mapping? Say in the template, a mapping(uint256 => string) object has a key-value pair <10, "Hello">. Does the cloned contract have this pair as well?

Comment: Clone is a bit unfortunate naming in this case. I aimed to changed it so it's not that confusing, but forgot about the `createMinimalProxy()` function. Plus the linked article uses the "clone" naming as well... It does **not** clone storage values (incl. mapping). It only creates a proxy to the bytecode (the actual functionality). But the proxy contract uses its own storage, unrelated to the implementation contract storage (and its history). The `initialized` bool in the implementation just prevents anyone to execute the `init()` function directly on the implementation (without proxy).

Comment: In order to fully understand this question, I must ask one more question: is the storage of a contract located at a separate location? Which means mapping, array, etc are not part of the bytecode of a contract? Is this true?

Comment: I later did some experiments and the full question can be found here: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/do-values-get-cloned/8055/4?u=maxaero

Comment: @Maxareo "is the storage of a contract located at a separate location" - that's correct. The actual stored values are stored in the EVM storage, and the bytecode only contains the definitions. There's an article in the docs that covers it in more depth, hope this helps - https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html

Comment: I've read this article hundreds of times, but didn't see any clear explanation about how storage is handled precisely by Solidity. Any other more in-depth materials?